# 1 IntelliSense: a value of type "StatementTable::StatementFunc" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "StatementTable::StatementState"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

StatementStateFunction [ ] is array of functions that all return StatementState and StateArray [GetInputToken(T)] [CurrentState] is a state table that tells StatementStateFunction [ ] which function to call, yet the compiler says it cannot assign a StatementFunc to a StatementState even though the methods called in StatementStateFunction[] all return a StatementState

In StatementTable.cpp

```
void StatementTable::BuildStatement (Token & T)
{
  StatementState CurrentState (StartStatement);
  do
  {
    CurrentState = StatementStateFunction [ StateArray[GetInputToken(T)][CurrentState] ];
  } 
  while (CurrentState != StatementComplete);
}
```

In StatementTable.h

```
typedef StatementState          (*StatementFunc)    (Token &);

static  Token::UChar        StateArray [NumTokeInputs] [NumberStates]; 
static  StatementFunc       StatementStateFunction  [];
```

Comment: The functions should return an index for the array, and the array should retrieve a value appropriate to assign.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze this expression:

```
CurrentState = StatementStateFunction [ StateArray[GetInputToken(T)][CurrentState] ];
```

You have three array indizes here, `GetInputToken(T), CurrentState, StateArray[x][y]`. Array indizes have to be integral numbers (`int`, `short`, `char`, `long` etc.).

- `GetInputToken` seems to be a function. From your source I cannot tell whether it returns an integral type or not.
- `CurrentState` is of type `StatementState`. It's not clear what that type is, but if its not of integral type nor has an implicit conversion to such a type, it cannot be used as array index.
- `StateArray[x][y]` is of type `Token::UChar`. Thyt should be ok, `UChar` looks like a typedef for an integral type.

What remains of the expression is the assignment. It has the form `CurrentState = StatementStateFunction[x]`. `StatementStateFunction[x]` is a `StatementFunc`, i.e. a function pointer. `CurrentState` is of type `StatementState`. **You cannot assign that function pointer to a `StatementState`**, at least that is what the error message says.

I assume you want to *call* that function, probably with the Token given as argument to `BuildStatement`. The code, made a bit more readable, would look like this:

```
void StatementTable::BuildStatement (Token & T)
{
  StatementState CurrentState = StartStatement;
  do
  {
    auto tokenIndex = GetInputToken(T);
    auto funcIndex = StateArray[tokenIndex][CurrentState];

    auto function = StatementStateFunction[funcIndex];
    //this is what was missing: the function call
    CurrentState = function(T);
  } 
  while (CurrentState != StatementComplete);
}
```